# How can I get all values from a specific key in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I got a few documents in mongoose that looks something like this:

```json
[
    {
        _id = "...",
        name = "abc123",
        colors = [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
        _id = "...",
        name = "def431",
        colors = [4, 2, 1]
    },
    {
        _id = "...",
        name = "htl534",
        colors = [3, 5, 7]
    },
    {
        _id = "...",
        name = "lwq154",
        colors = [9, 1, 4]
    }
]
```

From these documents I'd like to get an array with all the values from the keys named `name`, it would look something like this: `["abc123", "def431", "htl534", "lwq154"]`. How could I achive this? I thought about using some sort of querys or some find function, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use an `aggregate` query and avoid loop using a simple `$group` like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "result": {
        "$push": "$name"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dh8PQ2M20t8)

With this query you are adding all values into an array calling `result`. You can also use `$addToSet` to avoid duplicates. Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-AySzNCjwHh)

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
  const data = await Model.find(); // use your model name here, this will store every document in an array
  const result = [];
  data.forEach((item) => result.push(item.name)); //for every document in data array, we store the name onto the result array
  return res.status(200).send(result);
} catch (error) {
  return res.status(500).send(error);
}
```